# Walked the Path trophy on New Game+?

Tags: achievements, the-witcher-3

I completed The Witcher 3 on "Blood and Broken Bones" difficulty and want to try for "Death March" using my current gear (thankfully NG+ came along). Am I still eligible for the trophy for completing the game on "Death March" even though I'm carrying over gear from a lower difficulty playthrough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forums.cdprojektred.com/threads/45519-New-Game-is-coming-it-seems?p=1866418&viewfull=1#post1866418) by CDPR Community Manager Marcin Momont:

> You can obtain the Death Match achievement when playing the NG+ mode.

I'm confident, based on context, that he means the Death March achievement by this, and so you are eligible.