# Can all trophies be earned in new game +?

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

I've just started the story again in new game + and want to know if I can get the missed trophies. E.g currently I'm level 34,5, will I get the Trophy if I reach level 35 in the new game+?

### Update

As mentioned in the comments by Jeeva and his link to [**this question**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232625/walked-the-path-trophy-on-new-game/232642)

> You can obtain the Death Match achievement when playing the NG+ mode.

Whats absolutely correct and that would be a duplicate (See comments).

---

But I want to know what's about the other Trophys? The dev in the same Forum says you can obtain the play on death march trophy buit also says

> What carries over? 
>   Player experience (if you're below level 30 when finishing the vanilla game, you will be bumped to level 30 for the start of NG+), items (**excluding**: quest items, books & letters, Gwent cards, usable items, **trophies**), money and alchemy recipes.

So Players start at lvl 30 in NG+, will they still get the Trophy for reaching level 35?

Comment: Was going to flag this as a possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232625/walked-the-path-trophy-on-new-game/232642, but apparently that can only happen with upvoted answers. Anyway, as the current answer here shows, yes (confirmed with source in linked answer).

Comment: @Jeeva the link you've posted dont answer my question. The dev says `You can obtain the Death Match achievement when playing the NG+ mode.` But above next to `What carries over? - [...] items (excluding: quest items, books & letters, Gwent cards, usable items, **trophies**)[...]` so what about the other trophies that are not "play the wholle game on death march"? e.g. you start ng+ at level 30 will you get the lvl35 trophy?

Comment: Apologies, but I believe the dev means trophies (i.e. the severed heads of monsters) in the exclusions. My point was more that the dev says that achievements are possible in the NG+, there - though my memory might have been flawed. Assuming that the "reach 35" achievement is "get to level 35" and not "gain 35 levels"...

Comment: @Jeeva I get your point however its an "the dev means this and that I guess" answer which I dont want to accept here and still my question dont looks like a dupe for me ;). And yea i guess the dev means that you can still get trophies but can you still get all of them? Thats the thing i wanna know

Comment: Ha! Yes, fair enough. I'm reading both questions abstracted to "can I get achievements in NG+" which is bad form on my part. The answer is certainly yes, but you'll have a hard time getting non-anecdotal sourcing. I believe I have a NG+ save at roughly 34, so can test this if noone else manages to convince you in the meantime.

Comment: I'll edit the title a bit just to make it more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Achievements / Trophies can be obtained in New Game+, including `Munchkin` (tested this evening in NG+).

[image: Munchkin Achieved in NG+]

However, progress on some achievements are reset - these achievements being any of the quest or item related achievements (this of course being due to these items / events resetting with NG+) such as `Card Collector` or `Brawl Master`.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that while I was writing this out, I realized I hadn't thought to test the "kill (x) with (y)" achievements, so I'll go and test that now (and remove this comment when I have checked).

Comment: However good answer so far +1. If you've tested the kill x with y achievements i would accept your answer. Ty so far

Comment: You got any new information about the thing you didn't tried?

Comment: @Nitro.de: Ah, apologies - I tested for the Kill (x) with (y) achievements (which works), but realised I didn't know if it was carrying progress over from the original game. I'll edit it in, but please bear that in mind!

Comment: You're the best <3